# Replace post author in header by custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, author, headers

I'm managing a website for a printed magazine, which publishes some of it's best or most relevant articles on their website, like this one: https://dewekker.com/tweetal/4-mei-wees-erbij. This website is based on the Salient theme/framework, which uses the latest WP Bakery sitebuilder as post editor. But the posts simply use the default post template from WordPress.

In the post header, I would like to make two modifications:

1. Replace the default 'author' with a custom taxonomy, so I can get rid of using WordPress users as authors, because adding and managing author tags is much easier.
2. Add a custom taxonomy for 'photographer' just like the 'author' tag, which should only visible if a photographer tag is added to a post; this is to give credits for the used header image.

I have added two custom taxonomies with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin, that was the easy part; but I'm not a programmer, so I wouldn't know how to write the required new filter/function for adding a custom taxonomy in the post header. Once I have that, I do know how to add the new function and modify the header file in the active child theme. Any help is greatly appreciated.